# Kohana 3.0: how to get distinct entries?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.0

In a Kohana query, I need to retrieve only one element having the same id.
I have a method in the model:

```
public function next_products_images($id)
{
  return $this->where('product_image_product', '>=', $id-5)->limit(5)->find_all();  
  //for taking the previous five product pictures       
}
```

but the problem is that, from all the above results, generated by the method, I need to have only the ones that have "product_image_product" distinct. Can this be done using Kohana ORM?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work using a `group by`?

```
return $this->where('product_image_product', '>=', $id-5)->limit(5)->group_by('product_image_product')->find_all();
```